# UnitTest a SpringBatch FieldSetMapper

Tags: java, junit, spring-batch

I got the following custom FieldSetMapper

```
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.FieldSetMapper;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.FieldSet;
import org.springframework.validation.BindException;

import de.BasicProperty;

public class PersonItemFieldSetMapper implements FieldSetMapper<PersonItem> {

    @Override
    public PersonItem mapFieldSet(final FieldSet fieldSet) throws BindException {
        PersonItem person = new PersonItem();
        person.setLastName(fieldSet.readString(BasicProperty.BASICPROP_LASTNAME));
        person.setFirstName(fieldSet.readString(BasicProperty.BASICPROP_FIRSTNAME));
        person.setEmployeeType(fieldSet.readString("EmployeeType"));
        person.setFormOfAdress(fieldSet.readString(BasicProperty.BASICPROP_FORMOFADDRESS));
        person.setEMail(fieldSet.readString(BasicProperty.BASICPROP_EMAIL));
        person.setUpn(fieldSet.readString(BasicProperty.BASICPROP_UPN));
        person.setWorkforceId(fieldSet.readString(BasicProperty.BASICPROP_WORKFORCE_ID));
        person.setInstitute(fieldSet.readString(BasicProperty.BASICPROP_INSTITUTE));
        person.setPhoto(fieldSet.readString(BasicProperty.BASICPROP_PHOTO));

        return person;
    }

}
```

At the moment i am trying to write a unit-test for this mapper.
First Question: Is this reasonable?
Second Question: How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can write Test Cases for mapFieldSet()

```
You can always write such test cases to make sure your mapping are good!
// Using EasyMock to mock FieldSet  
@Test
public void mapFieldSetTest()
{
    FieldSet mockFieldSet = EasyMock.createMock(FieldSet.class);

    EasyMock.expect(mockFieldSet.readString("LNAME")).andReturn("Doe");
    EasyMock.expect(mockFieldSet.readString("FNAME")).andReturn("John");
    EasyMock.expect(mockFieldSet.readString("ETYPE")).andReturn("PART-TIME");
    EasyMock.expect(mockFieldSet.readString("FADDRESS")).andReturn("191, Santa Clara");
    EasyMock.expect(mockFieldSet.readString("EMAIL")).andReturn("john.Doe@fb.com");
    EasyMock.expect(mockFieldSet.readString("UPN")).andReturn("1111111111");
    EasyMock.expect(mockFieldSet.readString("WFID")).andReturn("22222222");
    EasyMock.expect(mockFieldSet.readString("INS")).andReturn("CA University College");
    EasyMock.expect(mockFieldSet.readString("PIC")).andReturn("c:\\john_doe.jpg");

    EasyMock.replay(mockFieldSet);

    // call the method under test
    PersonItem actual = fieldSetMapper.mapFieldSet(mockFieldSet);

    EasyMock.verify(mockFieldSet);

    // assert actual data by getters..
}
```

Comment: Post your classes, i can help

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone comes across this question and is using Mockito instead of EasyMock, you can use the following code to unit test the mapper:

```
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;


import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.FieldSet;
import org.springframework.validation.BindException;

import com.example.demo.loader.model.TestResult;

public class PersonItemFieldSetMapperTest {

    private final PersonItemFieldSetMapper fieldSetMapper = new PersonItemFieldSetMapper();

    @Test
    public void shouldMapFieldsCorrectly() throws BindException  {
        FieldSet mockFieldSet = mock(FieldSet.class);
        when(mockFieldSet.readInt("LNAME")).thenReturn("Doe");
        when(mockFieldSet.readInt("FNAME")).thenReturn("John");
        // Repeat setup for the other fields

        PersonItem actual = fieldSetMapper.mapFieldSet(mockFieldSet);
        assertEquals("Doe", actual.getLastName());
        assertEquals("John", actual.getFirstName());
        // Repeat assertions for the other fields
    }
}
```